How to use a string value as a command in Lua
Using the following code:
local keymap = vim.keymap
local opts = { noremap = true, silent = true }

function jumpToClassDef()
   local test1 = ""
   local myClass = "<cmd> tag ." .. vim.fn.expand('<cword>') .. "<cr>"
   assert(loadstring(myClass))
   return print(myClass)
end

keymap.set("n", "<leader>-", function() jumpToClassDef() end, opts)

When I place the cursor on test1 and hit <leader>-, I receive the following error:
unexpected symbol near <

Why does this error occur and how do I solve it?

To answer your main question: to use a string value in a command in Neovim, you just use the string; however, it must be a well-formed Neovim command.
Inferring from your function names and the use of the Neovim tag command, it seems like you want to perform a tag search to find the definition of some identifier. To do this, you would normally enter command mode from normal mode by pressing :, and then entering the following:
tag <some_identifier>

To do the same via Lua code in Neovim, you would call vim.cmd with the above as a string argument:
vim.cmd(":tag <some_identifier>")

In your case, you want to use the word under the current cursor position as the identifier to be searched for, thus, the function to be called becomes:
vim.cmd(":tag " .. vim.fn.expand("<cword>")

Finally, you can map this function to the <leader>- key sequence via the following:
vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>-", function()
    vim.cmd(":tag " .. vim.fn.expand("<cword>"))
end, { noremap = true, silent = true })

To address the second question regarding the unexpected symbol, the error comes from the call to loadstring. loadstring takes a chunk, compiles it, and returns a function that can be called to execute the chunk. In parsing the chunk passed in, Lua unexpectedly encounters the angle bracket as it is not apart of the language's syntax, hence the error. The solution is to only pass valid Lua syntax and well-formed strings to loadstring. However, you shouldn't need to use it in Neovim. Note that loadstring has been deprecated since Lua 5.2. You should now just use load.
